# Reversing function breaks it

Tags: php

I asked this question, which i got solved pretty quickly with help:
[Reverse the way of function output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610877/reverse-the-way-of-function-output/26610938#26610938)

However, when i do what is suggested, it breaks the way that the javascript is working.

If i do this

```
$output = '<a class="w-portfolio-item-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'.$post->ID.'">' . $output;
```

Instead of this:

```
$output .= '<a class="w-portfolio-item-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'.$post->ID.'">'
```

the javascript stops working. But the output is reversed, as it should be. How can this be solved, but still having the output reversed?

Comment: Just a minor commenty thing; why not use [heredocs](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5673478/899126) for holding multi-line strings, especially since you can still embed variables within them?

Comment: More relevant: what do you mean that it breaks the way that JavaScript is working? Does anything appear in the console log? If you view the page source, does the resulting HTML look correct?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Uh, heredocs i have not worked with before - i will look into this, thanks! - The page source is completely the same, no matter how the output is generated. This is one of the reasons why i don't see how this cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

In your example this

```
$output = '<a class="w-portfolio-item-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'.$post->ID.'">' . $output;
```

would create this `$output`:

```
<a class="w-portfolio-item-anchor" href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'.$post->ID.'"><div class="w-portfolio">
                        <div class="w-portfolio-h">
                            <div class="w-portfolio-list">
                                <div class="w-portfolio-list-h">
```

**Tip:** Use `var_dump($output)` or `echo $ouput` in your code so you can see what's stored in the *$output* variable. As it seems with your current code you will have a messed HTML structure.

**EDIT:**

You are initializing the `$output` variable outside of the loop on line 35. I'm writing now some pseudocode how your code should work:

```
    //line 34
    $output =   '<div class="w-portfolio"> 
                    <div class="w-portfolio-h">
                        <div class="w-portfolio-list">
                            <div class="w-portfolio-list-h">';

    foreach( $posts as $post ) {  // Note: This is the while loop in your example

        $output .= '<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="'.$post->ID.'">'; //notice the .= which appends the string to variable declared on line 35

    }
    $output .=              '</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';

    return $output;
```

**Don't** use `$output .= $output` or `$output  = 'bla bla' . $ouput` anywhere here. That would break the HTML structure you want to create with your code. Be conscious your $output variable starts with `$output = '<div class="w-portfolio">`.

Please **remove** the `. $output;` from `</div>'. $output;` on line 105 in your code.

Try this [PasteOfCode](http://paste.ofcode.org/MeT7vPAU7tsbssnghEAGdx)